# HTML in a HTML::link call

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm using the `Bootstrap` CSS framework to power my site and I'm trying to create a menu with it. How do I use HTML in a `HTML::link` call?

```
{{ HTML::link('#', 'Account<b class="caret"></b>', [
    'id'          => 'drop1',
    'data-toggle' => 'dropdown',
    'class'       => 'no-ajaxy']) }}
```

It seems to be being escaped by Laravel, though.

Output:

```
<a href="#" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="no-ajaxy">Account&lt;b class="caret"&gt;&lt;/b&gt;</a>
```

Expected Output:

```
<a href="#" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="no-ajaxy">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

How do I stop Laravel escaping the output? Thanks!

Comment: I belive you can add a triple {{{ }}} to have a raw output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping it with `HTML::decode()`. The method converts entities to HTML characters.

```
{{ HTML::decode(HTML::link('#', 'Account<b class="caret"></b>', [
                'id'          => 'drop1',
                'data-toggle' => 'dropdown',
                'class'       => 'no-ajaxy'])) }}
```

And you'll get the caret icon rendered.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the link() method can be seen here: http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Html.HtmlBuilder.html#113-129

As you can see, $this->entities (which is just a wrapper for htmlentities, converting all special characters to entities) is being called on $title. There is no way of stopping this behaviour unless you want to put in a lot of work to overwrite the HtmlBuilder.